# How to Debug JNI C File in NDK android

Tags: android

I want to check the value of the variable in JNI C NDK android, Can anybody help? I need  similar to

```
System.out.println(""+values);
```

in android.

Answer (score 2):

Define this at the top of the class and try to use like this

```
 #define LOG_TAG "ProjectName"
 #define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
 #define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
 #define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
 #define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
 #define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
 #define LOG_ASSERT(_cond, ...) if (!_cond) __android_log_assert("conditional", LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Use like this it will helps you :)

```
 LOGV("Hello World Sample...!");
```

Comment: Hey for this is i need to add anything in the Android.mk? I'm getting the error    'LOG_TAG' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Yes you have to add this LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

Comment: i have added the header file  #include <android/log.h>, but above runtime error

Comment: and add above line in Android.mk file so it will work

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it does not display my variable value with the message, im using as  : LOGD("Hello", "Debug", output_buf);

Comment: What is output_buf is it what kind of vaiable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56995/discussion-between-deepak-and-android-dev).